# What does “Pear” mean in “The Princess and the Pear” episode of Bones?

Tags: title, bones

The episode [“The Princess and the Pear”](http://bones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Princess_and_the_Pear) of the TV series Bones is about the murder of a “princess” (actually a booth babe at a convention playing a princess). The title seems to be an allusion to “The Princess and the Pea”, but I didn't notice anything about a pear in the episode.

What does the pear in the title of the episode refer to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1359122/synopsis):

> The murder weapon was a "medieval torture device" called the "[Pear of Anguish](http://www.oddee.com/item_96596.aspx)." The device was inserted into the victim's mouth and then slowly opened, crushing the orifice outward.

[image: Image of Pear of Anguish from www.oddee.com/item_96596.aspx]

Comment: Talk about spoilers in the tile.